# how can I store 20 digit number to 64-bit Register in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, intel-syntax

```
   .intel_syntax noprefix

number1:
    .quad 8403406020084561865 , 3325915310126341549 , 1038926090642473899 , 12330590014810845464

    mov r12,[number1+0]
    mov r13,[number1+8]
    mov rcx,[number1+16]
    **mov rsi,[number1+24]**
```

I can store "8403406020084561865 , 3325915310126341549 , 1038926090642473899" with no problem.
But when ı want to put **12330590014810845464** (20-digit number) to my register I have a problem.

And when I debug my code I see like this;

rsi = -6116154058898706152

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: There is no problem. You just need to print it as unsigned. E.g. in gdb use `p/u $rsi`

Comment: Unrelated, but normally you'd want to do `mov r12, [rip + number1 + 0]`.  RIP-relative addressing is the standard x86-64 way to access static data, not 32-bit absolute like you're using.